# Input in the facebook hacker cup

Tags: javascript

Does the input file need to be directly processed by the program?

say in the latest Beautiful strings question,

> 5
>
> ABbCcc
>
> Good luck in the Facebook Hacker Cup this year!
>
> Ignore punctuation, please :)
>
> Sometimes test cases are hard to make up.
>
> So I just go consult Professor Dalves

how would i handle it say in javascript?

Many thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you want

Comment: i don't know how to process the input on javascript,
is the program required to process the raw input or can i input each field seperately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use the [node.js filesystem api](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html) (also write your code in node.js - it's on google v8 so it should be fast enough for this one)

**EDIT**

I thought about your problem and it can be more simply solved (without using node.js) making a AJAX request to the file. You can achieve this like so :

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {   // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    // This logs the input.txt contents in the console.
    // You can do whatever you want with it
    console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","input.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

If you are a beginner you can read more stuff about AJAX requests on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP)

You can choose the method that suites better for you! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. i know this question was dodgy in the first place.

Comment: Which function should i be looking at?

Comment: check their documentation should be there ! Good luck!